# VBA EXCEL Sorting

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

Macro `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` paste in `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Const adrs As String = "F4:F50"

    Select Case Sh.Name
        Case "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
            If Not Intersect(Target, Worksheets(Sh.Name).Range(adrs)) Is Nothing Then
               Call Sort(Sh.Name)
            End If
        Case Else
    End Select
End Sub
```

Macro `Sub Sort(shtNme As String)` paste in `Module1` module

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sort(shtNme As String)
    On Error GoTo the_end
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtNme)
        .Range("N3:O50").ClearContents
        .Range("E3:F50").Copy Destination:=Range("N3")

        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("O4:O50"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange Range("N3:O50")
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

        .Range("A4").Select
    End With

    the_end: Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I can not get this code to run in excel 2016. I also can't step through this code either. If I try to step through code it just brings up an empty Marco Box.
The code will compile though.

I am trying to sort drivers by name based on time worked. Other code that I have used in the past seems to be crossing talking between sheets. I have also noticed that the workbook itself is slow loading and unloading.

Any Ideas?

I post my workbook but its to big.

Comment: take off your on error for a start. if anything is going wrong to cause the problem you're hiding the issue.

Comment: Write `application.EnableEvents=True` in the immediate window. Press Enter. Then write `Stop` after `Const adrs As String = "F4:F50"` and check whether the event works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange` is an event. You cannot step on it, it gets activated when something is changed in the workbook.

Try writing `Application.EnableEvents=True` in the Immediate Window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Change your code like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As 
Range)
Const adrs As String = "F4:F50"
Stop
...
```

Now change something on your sheet, and see how the event fires. It will stop on the `Stop` line, thus you can debug from there.

Comment: Ok, so from doing this I see that it runs through the code but than then it skips the call line of code. Therefore, the sort module is never called. Also is there a way to see the value its getting for sh.name?

Comment: @Daisy509th - `msgbox (sh.name)`

Comment: So, Sh.name is returning the proper values. Therefore, my code " If Not Intersect(Target, Worksheets(Sh.Name).Range(adrs)) Is Nothing Then
               Call Sort(Sh.Name)
            End If" So i guessing there is something wrong with my line of code dealing with the logic or argument. Any Ideas? Also thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @Daisy509th - put a stop sign and press F8 to debug. Probably you Target is not within the `F4:F50` range. Or something similar.

Comment: So,question, Can the problem be that "Sh.name" = Tuesday and not "Tuesday"?    Meaning the code line looks like this " Worksheets(Tuesday).Range("F4:F50") instead of "Worksheets("Tuesday").Range("F4:F50")" because the .Range = "F4:F50".   I am thinking that Tuesday needs to read "Tuesday" for syntax purposes

Comment: @Daisy509th- write `msgbox(Worksheets(Tuesday).Range("F4:F50").Address)` and see the answer. If it is an error, try to put it with parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

```
Const adrs As String = "A4:B50"

Select Case Sh.Name
    Case "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
        If Not Intersect(Target, Worksheets(Sh.Name).Range(adrs)) Is Nothing Then

          Call Sort(Sh.Name)

        End If
     Case Else
  End Select
End Sub
```

So this fixes the problem and by the other user teaching me how to debug this type of code I found the problem.